# Mouse cursor disappears when I play video in VLC

Tags: 13.04, mouse, vlc, pointers

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 (I had 13.04 before, but I made clean install) and as soon as I play video in VLC my mouse pointer disappears... then I can get it back only when I turn off and then turn on my touchpad with function key on keyboard. After a second or two it disappears again... Then when I turn off VLC it's working fine again...
When I use other video player (like Totem) it doesn't happen... Only with VLC...

It's asus vivobook, with nvidia optimus card on bumblebee (nvidia-304) and it has got a touch screen(which is finally working in 13.10)
I did not have this problem with any other ubuntu or any other distro...

Any ideas...???

Thanks...

Comment: same problem here in Kubuntu 16.04.

Comment: same problem in Ubuntu 16.10

Answer (score 1):

Daniel's answer contained the vital clue. I had the same issue. You can install latest version using an additional repository. You can google on below instructions. Note there are 2 such repositories "stable daily" which at time of writing contains the 2.0.9 version (still has mouse disappearing act) and the "master daily" (with currently version 2.2.0 which solves the bug)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Answer (score 0):

It was resolved with vlc 2.1.1 update... It's not in Ubuntu 13.10 sources... need to install from downloaded sources or custom PPA...